# Python - chaining of or operators in if statement don't provide expected results

Tags: python

Trying to chain OR operators in an if statement to cut down on redundant code but it seems only the first 2 operators are executed.

what I have now which works, but is messy

```
if out is "" or out != "sql":
    if out !=  "csv":
        print '\t*** ERROR  **'
    else:
        break
else:
    break
```

Trying to do similar to the following:

```
if out is "" or out != "sql" or out !=  "csv":
    print '\t*** ERROR  **'     
else:
    break
```

If the var is equal to blank, or not equal to sql or csv, then print an error, else continue.

```
Output {sql|csv}: csv
        *** ERROR **
```

The above should be `!= csv (False)` and continue to the next line, not printing out the error

Comment: Shouldn't that be `and`? Also note that `"" != "sql"`, so the initial check seems redundant.

Comment: please post the outer/external scope (I guess `while/for` loop), it may also be potentially optimised

Comment: Don't use `is` when you mean `==`. The more idiomatic way of testing for an empty string is to use the value itself in a boolean context: `if not out or out != "sql"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another alternative

```
if a not in ["sql", "csv"]:
```

Answer (score 1):

This

```
if out is "" or out != "sql":
    if out !=  "csv":
```

Is equivalent to

```
if (out is "" or out != "sql") and (out !=  "csv"):
```

Comment: exactly what I was after, knew it needed brackets somewhere but also confused the operations. cheers